# How to iterate over all values() in a QMultiHash

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, iterator, multimap

I need to iterate over a `QMultiHash` and examine the list of values that correspond to each key.  I need to use a mutable iterator so I can delete items from the hash if they meet certain criteria.  [The documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmutablehashiterator.html) does not explain how to access all of the values, just the first one.  Additionally, the API only offers a `value()` method.  How do I get all of the values for a particular key?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
QMutableHashIterator<Key, Value*> iter( _myMultiHash );
while( iter.hasNext() )
{
    QList<Value*> list = iter.values();  // there is no values() method, only value()
    foreach( Value *val, list )
    {
        // call iter.remove() if one of the values meets the criteria
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be better to use recent documentation:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmultihash.html

In particular:

```
QMultiHash<QString, int>::iterator i = hash1.find("plenty");
 while (i != hash1.end() && i.key() == "plenty") {
     std::cout << i.value() << std::endl;
     ++i;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

For future travelers, this is what I ended up doing so as to continue use of the Java style iterators:

```
QMutableHashIterator<Key, Value*> iter( _myMultiHash );
while( iter.hasNext() )
{
    // This has the same effect as a .values(), just isn't as elegant
    QList<Value*> list = _myMultiHash.values( iter.next().key() );  
    foreach( Value *val, list )
    {
        // call iter.remove() if one of the values meets the criteria
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all values of a `QMultiHash` as in a simple `QHash`:

```
for(auto item = _myMultiHash.begin(); item != _myMultiHash.end(); item++) {
  std::cout << item.key() << ": " << item.value() << std::endl;
}
```

It is just that the same key may appear several times if there are multiple values using the same key.